# Why does NLopt have L-BFGS but not BFGS?

Tags: optimization

NLopt, the "free/open-source library for nonlinear optimization, providing a common interface for a number of different free optimization routines..." has a `L-BFGS` routine but seemingly, no `BFGS` routine. The closest I can see in the [list of algorithms](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/) might be the `SLSQP` routine which does use `BFGS`. I have two questions:

1. Why is there no `BFGS` routine?
2. Should I just use the `L-BFGS` routine instead?

Some context. I am using `R` which has a basic `optim` function that allows you to choose `BFGS` and `L-BFGS` as algorithms. However, one situation where it is not possible to use `L-BFGS` instead of `BFGS` is when the objective function evaluates to `NaN` at points of the search space. My problem only involves about ten parameters so memory is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the algorithms are similar, their implementation is quite different: BFGS often constructs and stores the approximated Hessian explicitly, while L-BFGS uses the two-loop recursion by Jorge Nocedal. You can mimic BFGS by setting nlopt_set_vector_storage to a large number (at least the number of iterations).